# Can I remove a category from the Dash-home

Tags: internet, settings

When I type something in the dash-home the system searches the internet and displays choices from there. Is it possible to remove this feature? If it is, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to disable for example the searches from the internet, you can use this code:

```
 V=`/usr/bin/lsb_release -rs`; if [ $V \< 12.10 ]; then echo "Good news! Your version of Ubuntu doesn't invade your privacy."; else gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search none; if [ $V \< 13.10 ]; then sudo apt-get remove -y unity-lens-shopping; else gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"; fi; if ! grep -q productsearch.ubuntu.com /etc/hosts; then echo -e "\n127.0.0.1 productsearch.ubuntu.com" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts >/dev/null; fi; echo "All done. Enjoy your privacy."; fi
```

Just copy the code into a terminal, press enter and Type your password. This code is from [fixubuntu](https://fixubuntu.com/) will Turn off "Remote Search" and block connections to Ubuntu's ad server.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings> Security & Privacy and click on the "Search" tab. There, you can turn this feature on and off.